# How to ignore a property on Swagger body input but still show on responses?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle and Swagger UI to automatically generate API documentation.

My person endpoint uses the following PersonViewmodel:

```
public int? ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

My endpoint method takes in a PersonViewmodel as the body and returns a PersonViewmodel using an IActionResult. However, I don't want the user defining an ID as that is generated by the business logic. In the code if an ID is set it is ignored.

How can I change the Swagger UI to not show the ID in the Example value for the body input but still show the ID for the Example value for the responses?

I have found many ways to remove properties completely from Swagger UI such as `[JsonIgnore]` or setting the property to `internal` or `private`. But how can I remove a property from the input example in swagger but keep it in the output/responses example?

Comment: In my view it shouldn't be the same model in the first place. Easy one would be to have a model without the Id for the request and inherit one from that with the id for the response.

Comment: @Ralf that makes sense. I didn't want 2 different models for the sake of it. But using inheritance would make it easier.

Comment: As my comment didn't answer your actual question and time has moved on so the initial comment has infiltrated your mind. I think you would have to write a so called IDocumentFilter and register that one with Swashbuckle. In the Documentfilter you can then filter out the things you don't want to reach the created swagger file.

Comment: For the Documentfilter you then might want to create an additional attribute to mark the property(just show in request or response) and the Documentfilter can react on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way now with now. There are two things you need to do

1. Annotate with SwaggerSchema found in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;

```
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

2. EnableAnnotations in AddSwaggerGen

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.EnableAnnotations();
    });
```

See more about it in the [Documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations)

Comment: What if the same model is used for an update/PUT though? I would want read-only for an insert/POST and the id would need to be specified for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the attribute `[BindNever]` above the property like

```
[BindNever]
public int? Id {get;set;}
```

Also, please Check if you're using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize, that could be the reason your System.Text's `JsonIgnore` attribute didn't work.